# Access nested functions within a Python class

Tags: python, oop

I am new to OOP and I am struggeling with simple concepts.
An example:

```
class test():
    def a(self):
        # how can I access here the function b()
        b = self.a.b()
        def b ():
            return 2
        return b

test = test()
test.a()
```

Here I get the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'b'
```

I tried also a different versions with:

```
b = self.b()
```

Then I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: test instance has no attribute 'b'
```

Thank you veru much for hour help

Answer (score 4):

First, declare the function before attempting to call it.
Then call it directly by name. You do not need to use `self` or any other form of indirection since the function `b()` is local to method `a()`:

```
class test():
    def a(self):
        def b():
            return 2

        return b()

test = test()
test.a()
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the function b in the class not function a and then call self.b().